# UIViews with embedded scroll views (UITableView, UICollectionView) are ambiguous with Auto Layout in Xcode 6 b2. Bug or reason?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, ios8, xcode6

Here's an example project: http://cl.ly/1d0B1H0s0J0z

If I put a `UIView` in a `UIViewController` and pin it to its edges, it works fine. Same with a `UIImageView`, however if I use one a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` I get warnings that the view has "ambiguous scrollable content height/width". The same constraints work fine under Xcode 6 beta 1, but in this new beta 2 seed, it won't.

Is this a change to how views with embedded scroll views are handled? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7):

Some info on Apple developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/987563#987563

I'm pretty sure this is a bug.